# AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'mean'

Tags: python, tensorflow, shap

I am working with tensorflow 2.12.0 and I have problmes to use shap.DeepExplainer, my version is 0.41.0. When I ask for the explainer.shap_values I get: AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'mean'

```
import tensorflow as tf 
distrib_samples = x_train[:200] 
x_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(distrib_samples) 
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, x_tensor) 
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x_tensor)
```

```
  5 x_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(distrib_samples)
  6 explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, x_tensor)
----> 7 shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x_tensor) 
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

I tried to use enable and disable the eager but it doesn`t work. In my opnion is something with the version